# Trigonometric integral on complex plane

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to take the integral of $$\int_0 ^{2\pi}{d\theta\over {3+\sin\theta+\cos\theta}}$$

I did this multiple times, and get an answer of $24\pi/(1+i)$, I am really not sure about this one and it has been bothering me, and then my friends get $2\pi/\sqrt7$.

What answer do you have? You don't even have to type out the procedure. I just want to know what the final answer should be. Thanks!

This is what I did when use the $z=e^{i\theta}$ substitution, factor, rationalize, and then factor $1/2$ out, and I get

$3+sin\theta+cos\theta=1/2(6-iz+i/z+z+1/z)$, and then I put it in the original integration

$$\int_0 ^{2\pi}{d\theta\over {3+\sin\theta+\cos\theta}}=2/i \int {1\over{6z-iz^2+i+z^2+1}}dz=2/i\int {1\over{(1-i)z^2+6z+(1+i)}}dz$$

And when I solve for z using the Quadratic Formula, I get ${3+/- \sqrt 7}\over {1-i}$, and the 1-i stuck through out the problem.

Comment: The answer is $2\pi/7$. Note that the integrand is real on your region, so the answer cannot be complex. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%283+%2B+Sin%5Bt%5D+%2B+Cos%5Bt%5D%29%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+2+Pi%7D%5D

Comment: @Jonathan I use the $z=e^{i\theta}$ substitution, and ended up with a quadratic formula and the answer is divided by $1+i$, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my comment should read $2\pi/\sqrt{7}$. I don't think I can edit it at this point.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the approach that you described. It's probably an arithmetic mistake. Did you remember the $i$ in the denominator when you expanded $\sin$ in exponentials?

Comment: @Jonathan: I have done it for the 5th time, and I still have the (1+i) attached to my answer, now I have $(1+i)2\pi/\sqrt 7$, and the only reason why my friend gets $2\pi/sqrt7$ is that she forgets to divide by 2a when using the quadratic formula, it is really strange :(

Comment: @Jonathan: and yes, I remembered the i in the denominator

Comment: @Akaichan would you mind editing in your process into the question, so we can read it to find the mistake?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: I edited it

Comment: @Akaichan you didn't make the substitution $d\theta = dz/iz$

Comment: I did! I multiply z in, left the i out, thats where the 2/i came from

Comment: @Akaichan It looks a little like you forgot a factor of $1-i$ in the denominator, $$\frac{2}{i}\int \frac{dz}{(1-i)z^2+6z+(1+i)} = \frac{1+i}{i}\int \frac{dz}{z^2+3(1+i)z + i},$$ and with the zero $z_0 = \frac{\sqrt{7}-3}{2}(1+i)$ of the denominator inside the unit circle, you get the residue $$\frac{1}{2z_0+3(1+i)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}(1+i)}$$ and the expected result.

Comment: No, you can leave the coefficient as is. It's just easier to forget to multiply something when you do, so when you get the wrong results, small steps reducing everything to canonical form is a good strategy to avoid the mistake.

Comment: @DanielFischer: you just saved me from banging my head against my head this afternoon. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should use some math software to verify the answer. For example, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D+1%2F%283%2Bsin%28x%29%2Bcos%28x%29%29dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$
\sin\vartheta+\cos\vartheta=\sqrt{2}\sin(\vartheta+\pi/4),
$$
and hence
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\vartheta}{3+\cos\vartheta+\sin\vartheta}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\vartheta}{3+\sqrt{2}\cos\vartheta}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2\, d\vartheta}{6+\sqrt{2}(\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}+\mathrm{e}^{-i\vartheta})}\\=-2i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}\, d\vartheta}{6\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}+\sqrt{2}(\mathrm{e}^{2i\vartheta}+1)}=-\sqrt{2}\,i\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z^2+3\sqrt{2}\,z+1}
$$